# Deployed web app on Heroku, but it does not work

Tags: ajax, spring, heroku, deployment, spring-security

Deployed application on Heroku (zrecipe.herokuapp.com) but it does not work (work perfect local). Code is at https://github.com/zzheads/RecipeSite.
Development tools shows error message:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://zrecipe.herokuapp.com/' 
was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 
'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'. 
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I think problem is my ajax requests in program are trying load something from HTTP, without SSL, page is supposed to be secure but my app are trying to load non-secured objects. How I can get rid of this?

Comment: So better change to `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js`

Comment: Yep, thanks, already fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the `-s` command line parameter.